# SQL limit error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce-3.5

I use this code in my project (SQL COMPACT):

```
"select Name 
from Drug 
where Name 
like '" + Dname + "%'  
limit 10"
```

`Dname` is a string value. The result is this error:

> There was an error parsing the query.
>
> [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 44,Token in error = LIMIT ]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: To what kind of database are you connecting (MySQL, Oracle,...)?

Comment: this one is for `mysql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138419/1275871), the proper syntax is `TOP(n)`, so try this:

```
"select TOP(10) Name 
from Drug 
where Name 
like '" + Dname + "%' "
```

Answer (score 4):

i think what you want is

```
"select TOP (10)  
from Drug 
where Name 
like '" + Dname + "%'  "
```

you should also try using parametrized queries:

```
 string qry = "select TOP(10) from Drugs where name like @dname";
 SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(qry, ConnectionString);
 oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dname", dname +  '%');
```

Comment: using this code too give me an error: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 12,Token in error = 10 ]

Comment: when i remove limit or top it worked corrct.but when i use them again ...error.

Comment: again: what's the error? can you try the run the same query in your local SQL server and see if it works there?

Comment: There was an error parsing the query[ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 12,Token in error = 10 ]        i haven't a sql server.its sql compact 3.5

Answer (score 3):

Never use string concatenations to build SQL queries. Always use parametrized queries:

```
string connectionString = ....
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 FROM drug WHERE name LIKE @name";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Dname + '%');
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```